# Too many records extracted from RSS feed Scala

Tags: xml, scala, for-loop, rss

I need to extract some data from XML and write it to the database. I have created Record entity for that:

```
case class Record (title: String, description: String)
```

I want to write titles and descriptions to Record entities. If I have about 12 records in XML I want to have an output of 12 records. However, I get an output of 12*12 records, which means each record is printed 12 times. What may be the reason of it?

Here is the main method:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http("link")
      .timeout(connTimeoutMs = 2000, readTimeoutMs = 5000)
      .asString
    val xmlString = response.body
    val xml = XML.loadString(xmlString)
    val titleNodes = (xml \\ "item" \ "title")
    val descriptionNodes = (xml \\ "item" \ "description")

    val output: Seq[Record] = for{
      title <- titleNodes
      description <- descriptionNodes
    }yield Record(title.text, description.text)
    output.foreach(println)
}
```

I have started to code in Scala only recently so I would be grateful for any advice!

Comment: Have you looked at the raw XML string? Are you sure it only contains 12 items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are 12 items and each item has one title and one description, that means that there are 12^2 possible pairs of title and description, which is what your code is computing. If you want just the title and description per item, well then your outer loop should be on the items:

```
for {
  item <- xml \\ "item"
  title <- item \ "title"
  description <- item \ "description"
} yield Record(title.text, description.text)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!